# CKEditor Add new list plugin using UL tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to add a new list plugin similar to bulletedlist so I've created a new button but as i'm trying to use the UL tag it pairs the new button called arrowedlist with the bulletedlist button.

The reason I am doing this is so I can add a class to it (which I know how to do) so I can have 2 different buttons where 1 applies the default bullet list and the other applies UL tags with a class.

The basic question is: is there a way I can add a button that uses UL the same way as bulletedlist does without it pairing the buttons together?

```
    // Register commands.
        editor.addCommand( 'numberedlist', new listCommand( 'numberedlist', 'ol' ) );
        editor.addCommand( 'bulletedlist', new listCommand( 'bulletedlist', 'ul' ) );
        editor.addCommand( 'arrowedlist', new listCommand( 'arrowedlist', 'ul' ) );


        // Register the toolbar button.
        if ( editor.ui.addButton ) {
            editor.ui.addButton( 'NumberedList', {
                label: editor.lang.list.numberedlist,
                command: 'numberedlist',
                directional: true,
                toolbar: 'list,10'
            });
            editor.ui.addButton( 'BulletedList', {
                label: editor.lang.list.bulletedlist,
                command: 'bulletedlist',
                directional: true,
                toolbar: 'list,20'
            });
            editor.ui.addButton( 'ArrowedList', {
                label: editor.lang.list.arrowedlist,
                command: 'arrowedlist',
                directional: true,
                toolbar: 'list,30'
            });

        }
```

Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious,
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although **this is not straightforward** as list system wasn't designed to do such things, you can do something about that. You got to modify the code of the list plugin (`plugins/list/plugin.js`). These are basic assumptions to be implemented:

- Distinguish between different lists:

  - Each `<ol>` gets `data-numberedlist` attribute.
  - Each `<ul>` gets `data-bulletedlist` or `data-arrowedlist` attribute depending on your custom class.
- Add custom CSS for your class.
- Add custom class to newly created lists if the command defines one.
- Add custom attribute to every single list created with the button (see the first point).
- Make command's `refresh` distinguish between `<ul data-bulletedlist="true>` and `<ul data-arrowedlist="true>`.

I'm assuming that you have the latest CKEdtor (4.2). I'll do my best to guide you here. While reading this, please take a look on [The Gist](https://gist.github.com/oleq/6178233/revisions) implementing the following changes. This will definitely help you to get the context of what is different. So... good luck and let's go! ;)

---

## Things to be modified

### Add specific styles for your list

Put it outside of plugin definition, this is gonna be global for all editors:

```
CKEDITOR.addCss( 'ul.myclass { color: red } ' );
```

### Make listCommand() function accept custom class as parameter.

We got to allow the custom class and `data-name` attribute in [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

```
function listCommand( name, type, className ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.context = type;

    // Remember the class of this command.
    this.className = className;

    this.allowedContent = {};
    this.allowedContent[ type ] = {
        classes: className || '',
        attributes: 'data-' + name
    };
    this.allowedContent.li = true;
    this.requiredContent = type;
}
```

### Add the command for arrowedlist

Note `myclass` here.

```
editor.addCommand( 'arrowedlist', new listCommand( 'arrowedlist', 'ul', 'myclass' ) );
```

### Add the button

```
editor.ui.addButton( 'ArrowedList', {
    label: editor.lang.list.bulletedlist,
    command: 'arrowedlist',
    directional: true,
    toolbar: 'list,20'
});
```

### Add data-name attribute to all NEW lists

To distinguish between list types, add `data-name` attribute to the element:

```
listNode = doc.createElement( this.type );
listNode.data( this.name, true );
```

### Add your custom class to NEW arrowed lists.

```
if ( this.className )
    listNode.addClass( this.className );
```

### Extend refresh() in the prototype of listCommand

This ensures that arrowedlist button will change its state only if the `<ul>` has `data-arrowedlist`. Similar behavior for bulletedlist and numberedlist, of course.

```
if ( list && limit.contains( list ) ) {
    var isList = list.is( this.type ) && list.data( this.name );

    this.setState( isList ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF );
}
```

### Add dataprocessor rules

During editor's lifetime, each `<ol>` gets `data-numberedlist`. Accordingly each `<ul>` gets `data-arrowedlist` or `data-bulletedlist` depending on whether class `myclass` is set.

On the output, custom attributes are filtered out so data that you save is totally clean.

```
editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
    elements: {
        ol: function( element ) {
            element.attributes[ 'data-numberedlist' ] = true;
        },
        ul: function( element ) {
            var className = element.attributes.class;

            if ( className && className.match( /myclass/g ) )
                element.attributes[ 'data-arrowedlist' ] = true;
            else
                element.attributes[ 'data-bulletedlist' ] = true;
        }
    }
} );

editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
    elements: {
        ol: function( element ) {
            delete element.attributes[ 'data-numberedlist' ];
        },
        ul: function( element ) {
            delete element.attributes[ 'data-arrowedlist' ];
            delete element.attributes[ 'data-bulletedlist' ];
        }
    }
} );
```

---

## Testing

Try setting the following HTML in source view:

```
<ul class="myclass">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
</ul>
```

It should become a red list when goind back to WYSIWYG. Also the arrowedlist button will be the only one associated to such list.

Comment: Having a few conflict issues detailed below as it wouldnt fit in the comment box!

Answer (score 1):

@oleq

When attempting to change a bulleted list to a numbered list the functionality works but the numbered list button does not click down and still looks unclicked.

When trying to change from a bulleted list to an arrowed list the functionality does not work and the bulleted list buttons stays clicked down and vice versa for arrowed list to bulleted list.

When trying to change from a numbered list to an arrowed list the list changes to a normal bulleted list but the `<ul>` still has an attribute of `data-numberedlist="true"` even though the list changes to plain bullets.

When changing a unformatted list to and from a numbered list everything works fine including the button being clicked but this does not work with either of the other buttons being used in between.

Also when going from an arrowed list to a numbered list the `<ul>` tag changes to `<ol>` but applies the `class="arrowbullet" data-arrowedlist="true"` attributes to the `<ol>` tag, I can tell something is conflicting but I'm not quite sure where.

Comment: All you got to do is to track down the code responsible for changing list type from one to another and fix it so it changes `data-*` attribute ;)

Comment: I noticed it wasn't attached the right data-* attribute but wasn't 100% sure if that was causing this but thanks I'll give it a go!

Comment: I'm running out of ideas.. I've been debugging using chrome developer tools and using console.logs have seen that the changeListType and createList functions are working when they should be and the data attribute code looks legit I just cant quite seem to crack this one on my own :/

Comment: @oleq or is it a better idea to implement this in the format plugin, as I can easily make it add a custom class to a `<ul>` but it seems difficult to apply an `<li>` to each element